# How can I migrate photos from Microsoft OneDrive to Google Photos?

Tags: onedrive, google-photos

How can I migrate photos from [Microsoft OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/) to [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/)? Can I do it without having to download all the photos from OneDrive to my desktop and then uploading them to Google Photos?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways including free and paid, but I will show you the free way.

1. Google has announced new Google Photos that works with Google Drive, so you need to make sure that there is a Google Photos folder in your Google Drive.
2. Head to www.multcloud.com and register an account.
3. Confirm the accounts and start linking your cloud services
4. Click Transfer on the header of the website and select the folders you want to transfer. Your destination folder should be Google Photos.
5. Boom! You're done!

Let me know if you caught any issue.

Comment: Amazing solution. But When I select google drive, it shows the drive (with folders and files). I cant see google photos as destination. How can I get that?

Comment: The Google Photos folder is added automatically. Can you go to drive.google.com and check if there is any wizard to create it?

Comment: I found an issue with this solution, you need enough free space in your Google Drive Account to hold all the pictures in their original (high res) form. Using the app and copying from your PC has an option for a lower res but free unlimited space. So looks like I am back to uploading from my PC

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can **select the individual file by dropdown** eliminating having to use the entire folder unless that is what you are after.